# AVPlayerLooper doesn't loop through multiple videos

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, cocoa, avfoundation

I created a `AVPlayerView` for non-stop playback of 4 videos using `AVPlayerLooper`. The problem is: `AVPlayerView` shows only one looped video. But I need to play a sequence (4 videos).

**How to make `AVPlayerLooper` play all 4 videos and loop after that**?

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var viewOne: AVPlayerView!
    var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        let videos = (1...4).map { _ in
            Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "mov", 
                                          subdirectory: nil)![Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))]
        }
    
        viewOne.player = AVQueuePlayer(url: videos[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))])
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: videos[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4)))])
        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: viewOne.player as! AVQueuePlayer, templateItem: item)
        viewOne.player?.actionAtItemEnd = .advance
        viewOne.controlsStyle = .none

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
                                     selector: #selector(loopSequence), 
                                         name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, 
                                       object: viewOne.player?.currentItem)
    
        func loopSequence() {
            self.viewOne.player?.pause()
            self.viewOne.player?.currentItem?.seek(to: kCMTimeZero, completionHandler: nil)
            self.viewOne.player?.play()
        }
        loopSequence()
    }
}
```

Comment: `AVPlayerLooper` is for only ONE item. I'd suggest to create a queue of 4 `AVPlayerItem` and use this to detect the end and "restart/loop". https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361145/looping-a-video-with-avfoundation-avplayer

Comment: There are answers that are in Swift in the linked question. Did you try them?

Comment: Have you tried using [`AVQueuePlayer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avqueueplayer)

Comment: I'm using AVQueuePlayer.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that [this is an exact solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45598546/9333764) for your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding the solution that had been previously answered and posting it in the comments, @andy asked me to post it as a solution. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45598546/9333764) is the previous answer by Harish that solved his problem.

Comment: I can still help. I’ll be busy today but I’ll try to get to this tomorrow

Comment: Have you set breakpoints and stepped through to see what happens? Specifically at the line of code that is supposed to play the video

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168672/discussion-between-jake-and-andy).